# Installing tokudb under mariadb, plug in not found

Tags: mariadb, tokudb

I'm trying to install tokudb under mariadb the lazy way using the debs given here (ubuntu 13.04) https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-enable-tokudb-in-mariadb/

I should run
sudo apt-get install mariadb-tokudb-engine-5.5
but if I apt-cache search I get maria-db-tokudb-engine-10.0 (I have installed mariadb 10).

Just checking on the installation if I enter mysql and run

INSTALL SONAME 'ha_tokudb';
ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_tokudb.so' (errno: 2 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

Certainly, I can't find the plugins on my HDD under the mysql/plugin folder.   Have they been placed somewhere else?    Have I missed something?   Should I isntall tokudb following the instructions at the totutek site.

Many thanks for any advice.
Best
paul

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the exact way for you to resolve your issue, but downloading the tarball from www.tokutek.com will certainly work.  You'll need to do a manual install of it.

MariaDB is working to change their packaging going forward so the plugin will be available without a separate apt-get.  The fixed it in [this Jira ticket](http://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-5038).

Answer (score 0):

You should go to tokudb's official site in order to download the separate mysql or mariadb edition.
[TokuDB for mysql or mariadb link](http://www.tokutek.com/products/tokudb-for-mysql/)